# Error connecting to site when webscraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib3

I have the following code that has been working beautifully up until recently:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

# Create a session with retries
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)


url = "https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles"

#https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=256
params = {
    "store_id": "uk",
    "parent_id": 61,
    "page": 1,
    "sortBy": "pricedesc",
    "minPrice": 0,
    "maxPrice": 0,
    "perPage": 256,
}

# Initialize store and new_store lists
store = []
new_store = []

# current dateTime
now = datetime.now()

date = now.strftime("%d/%m %H:%M")
print('Time started', date)

# Make initial API request and parse response
response = session.get(url, params=params)  # Use the session for the request
data = response.json()

print(data)
```

However now I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    response = session.get(url, params=params)  # Use the session for the request
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 677, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 677, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 237, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7XXXXXXXXXXX>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

This error occurs 3 times due to connect=3. Any ideas how to get around this? The code was working absolutely fine until of recent. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do `ping google.com` in your terminal. If you can't connect then it's your network that's the issue. If you can connect, then it's either the site/endpoint you're trying to reach, or the way you're trying to reach it (rate limit, API key, VPN, proxy, etc)

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch I can ping google.com and the main site (smws.com) however not https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, I tested your code, and it needs user agent. It is a good practice to always include agents or headers in scrapers.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
```

```
import requests

url = "https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles"

params = {
    "store_id": "uk",
    "parent_id": 61,
    "page": 1,
    "sortBy": "pricedesc",
    "minPrice": 0,
    "maxPrice": 0,
    "perPage": 256,
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}

# Send GET request to the URL with the User-Agent header
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

print(data)
```

Before:
[image]
Now I tested it, and it works.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that resulted in the same error in my side.

Comment: Try this: `curl "https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=256"`

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.smws.com port 443: Operation timed out

Comment: Try just visiting the link in your browser, you could be maybe blocked? trying too many times?

Comment: I can access via the browswer, just not using the above script or via terminal for some reason.

Comment: try a simple url like google, `curl "https://www.google.com/"` if that does not work, check your hosts file or dns

Comment: I can curl google, however not https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=256 for some reason

Comment: Maybe your IP got blocked from too many requests. If you have VPN try that, or wait to see if you get whitelisted automatically later. In any case I tested your code and got same error, adding requests and headers fixed it